# ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape

Tags: python, numpy

I am probably missing something obvious but I am stuck on this:

Inside `ipdb` session I was able to reduce my problem to this:

```
ipdb> type(scores)
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
ipdb> scores.shape
(23073, 50)
ipdb> scores[np.arange(scores.shape[0]), np.zeros(scores.shape[0], dtype=np.int)] += 10
*** ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
ipdb> scores.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

I was not able to reproduce this problem with at simple example:

```
In [24]: a = np.matrix(np.zeros((6,4))
)

In [25]: a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=np.int)] += 10

In [26]: a
Out[26]: 
matrix([[ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])

In [27]: a.dtype
Out[27]: dtype('float64')
```

Any ideas what could be going on? What should I check?

Comment: Are you trying to add 10 to the first column? Try `a[:,0] += 10`.

Comment: I was trying to do something more complicated, I just kept simplifying and go the this.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. On my local (simple example) I have `numpy 1.9.0` and on remote (ipdb session) I have `numpy 1.8.1`